# Cannot resolve SQLException: ColumnIndex out of range

Tags: java, sql, swing, resultset

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column index out of range.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1094)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:997)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:983)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:928)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetMetaData.getField(ResultSetMetaData.java:407)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetMetaData.getColumnName(ResultSetMetaData.java:258)
    at a.MyFrame.createTablePanel(MyFrame.java:58)
    at a.MyFrame.<init>(MyFrame.java:24)
    at a.MyFrame.main(MyFrame.java:19)
```

That's the stack trace i've got in class MyFrame.
And these are the codes:

```
MyFrame.createTablePanel().

public JPanel createTablePanel () {
        DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
        DB dB = new DB();
        dB.connectDB();
        ResultSet rs = dB.getData();
        try {       
            ResultSetMetaData rsMD = rs.getMetaData();
            String[] arr = new String[rsMD.getColumnCount()];
            for (int i = 0; i <= rsMD.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                arr[i] = rsMD.getColumnName(i+1);
            }
            tableModel.setColumnIdentifiers(arr);
            while (rs.next()) {
                for (int i = 0; i <= rsMD.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                    arr[i] = rs.getString(i+1);
                }
                tableModel.addRow(arr);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JPanel tablePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5,5));
        JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
        tablePanel.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        return tablePanel;
    }
```

it uses DB class to communicate with the Database:

```
DB Class.

public class DB {

    private final String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
    private final String user = "root";
    private final String pass = "khjthat";
    private final String table = "ungvien";
    Statement stmt;
    PreparedStatement pstmt;
    ResultSet rs;
    ResultSetMetaData rsMD;
    String str; //Query String.
    Connection connection;

    public DB() {
    }
    public void connectDB () {
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
                System.out.println("Driver Loaded!");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
                System.out.println("Connected!");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Class Not Found!");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Connection Error!");
        }
    }
    public void showData(ResultSet rs) {

            try {
                rsMD = rs.getMetaData();
                for (int i = 0; i < rsMD.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                    System.out.printf("\t%-10s ", rsMD.getColumnName(i+1));
                }
                System.out.println();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    System.out.printf("\t%-10s \t%-10s \t%-10s \t%-10s \n", rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4));
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            }
    }
    public ResultSet getData() {
        str = "select * from " + table + ";";
        try {
            stmt = connection.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(str);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return rs;
    }
    public ResultSet getDataTen(String ten) {
        str = "select ten,tuoi,truong,kn from " + table + " where ten = ? " ;
        try {
            pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(str);
            pstmt.setString(1, ten);
            rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return rs;
    }
    public void deleteTen (String ten) {
        str = "delete from " + table + " where ten = ? ";
        try {
            pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(str);
            pstmt.setString(1, ten);
            if (pstmt.executeUpdate() > 0) {
                System.out.println("Delete Successful!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Delete Error!");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Delete Error!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void insert (UngVien ungVien) {
        str = "insert into " + table + " values (?,?,?,?) ";
        try {
            pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(str);
            pstmt.setString(1, ungVien.getTen());
            pstmt.setInt(2, ungVien.getTuoi());
            pstmt.setString(3, ungVien.getTruong());
            pstmt.setInt(4, ungVien.getKn());
            if (pstmt.executeUpdate() > 0) {
                System.out.println("Insert Successful!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Insert Error!");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Insert Error!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void updateTen (String ten, UngVien ungVien) {
        str = "update " + table + " set tuoi =?, truong =?, kn =? where ten = ?";
        try {
            pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(str);
            pstmt.setInt(1, ungVien.getTuoi());
            pstmt.setString(2, ungVien.getTruong());
            pstmt.setInt(3, ungVien.getKn());
            pstmt.setString(4, ten);
            if (pstmt.executeUpdate() > 0) {
                System.out.println("Update Successful!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Update Error!");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Update Error!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        DB dB = new DB();
        dB.connectDB();
        dB.showData(dB.getData());
    }
}
```

I tested the DB class, and everything works well.

I have tried to debug this all this afternoon, but i cannot understand if it's right over there :(

I'm very new to JAVA, and i hope this question did not bother you guys.

Please give me some trick :(

Thanks so much.

Comment: The line 58 in my Eclipse editor frame is:
arr[i] = rsMD.getColumnName(i+1);

Comment: in `(int i = 0; i <= rsMD.getColumnCount(); i++)`, remove `=`

Comment: "java.sql.SQLException: Column index out of range." should be "java.sql.SQLException: Column index out of range [out of range value here]". :-)

Comment: Also change  rsMD.getColumnName(i+1); to  rsMD.getColumnName(i);

Comment: Thank you so much, ive got it, this is my mistake, actually, now i really see this is a stupid mistake, and i really encounter it not just once.
Thank you guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned by  user3145373 in comments

from

```
for (int i = 0; i <= rsMD.getColumnCount(); i++)
```

remove equal (=) sign and do as

```
for (int i = 0; i < rsMD.getColumnCount(); i++)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, im having a shame now :(

Answer (score 0):

Explaining further on the above answer

*Suppose someone asked you give me ten coins and set the counter on the first coin to zero so in that case you are going to him him until the count reaches nine right.*

Same is the case here you have initialized `i = 0` so you need to iterate it until the count reaches `totalCount-1`.

Or change to this

```
for (int i = 1; i <= rsMD.getColumnCount(); i++)
```